# Port Forward issues with modem or router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding, modem

I have a RT-AC68P Router That i am trying to port forward Port 28015 in order to host a server for a game called rust. Form some reason the port WILL NOT open no matter what i do i have been working on this for days. so far i have configed my router to open the port and turned off all firewalls that could possibly be in my way on all the computers as well as on the router its self. so i thought just for fun lets plug my computer right into the modem and see if the ports are even open without the router there at all and the ports are still closed..... how in the world do i port forward 28015 if the modem is stopping me? in the end i guess my question is. can my crap modem that charter gave me have a fire wall cause i have never heard of a modem having a fire wall and im so lost....

Comment: Your ISP may be blocking it. Some ISPs don't allow running servers on consumer connections ...

Comment: Forget your modem for a second. Plug your server into your router's WAN port plug in another computer to test on the LAN ports. If it works, your ISP may be blocking that port.  To work around this, can you use another port for this game?